# Informix Database Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, informix

My English being bad, I use a translator to communicate with you. Sorry if the sentences don't always make sense.

As the title suggests, I want to know if it is possible to connect an informix database with a laravel 7 application.
All the solutions I found on the web are not compatible with laravel 7.

Do you know, if at the moment it is possible to connect informix to laravel 7 ?

Thank you in advance for your help and your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Eloquent supports Informix. You can use PHP PDO though. A code snippet would be as follow:

```
$db = new PDO("informix:host=host.domain.com; service=9800;
    database=common_db; server=ids_server; protocol=onsoctcp;
    EnableScrollableCursors=1", "testuser", "tespass");
```

You may have to install Informix driver for PDO. You can read the links below:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-informix.connection.php

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.instnode.doc/php.htm